# In C++ loops, reuse large data structures and reset content or allocate new, which is faster?

Tags: c++, performance, loops, opencv, memory-management

Is it faster to allocate large data structures like OpenCV images or std:vectors outside a loop, that are used in every iteration of a loop, but need to be reset (e.g. set OpenCV Mat to Scalar(0))? Or should one just instantiate a new one inside the loop?

Edit:
I was looking for a rule of thumb, if creating a new default constructed OpenCV Mat containing zeros, is as fast, faster or slower than resetting the Mat in every loop. If there are too many different compiler behaviors affecting the outcome, so that one has to measure it, this would be an answer I was looking for too. Thanks to everybody, who are giving this a thought!

Comment: Just measure it.

Comment: I would assume reusing the datastructure will be faster if the object size is similar each iteration. Especially in the case of large datastructures allocating new space is an expensive operation. It is also very cache friendly if you reuse the same vector every time. Also ensure that when using a std::vector you call .reserve(size) if you know the required size in advance or have an idea how much you need (prevents dynamically sizing the vector multiple times).

Comment: I've noticed VC's optimizer taking a `std::vector` out of a loop. In that case there is no reason to obfuscate the code. So yeah, you need to measure.

Comment: Maybe you can reset your Mat structure but not memset the data, that would be the best. The problem with allocating new is that it's not trivial to measure, even on the same system with the same compiler sometimes allocation may be very fast, but once in a while it may require paging or some other significant kernel involvement, and become orders of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 4):

Allocating new space usually is an expensive operation, so always do it outside of loops if possible and reuse that space. In some cases, you don't even need to zero the matrix before using it again (for example, if you're going to set all the elements of the matrix).

However, as pointed by other people, you should measure the time. Sometimes the performance difference is so small that you'd better write the code the way it's cleaner and easier to follow.

Comment: This is a rule of thumb **at best** and I'm not sure how much merit it has even as rule of thumb. For starters, it depends a great deal on the meaning of "allocating new space"; stack allocation is virtually (often actually) free, and some dynamic memory allocators are quite good at exploiting "free, then allocate just as much again" cycles.

Comment: I agree, but since there is no more details, and he will have to init the allocated memory anyway, I'm pretty sure it's faster to just init memory than alloc + init

Comment: @delnan could you please clarify for me ""free, then allocate just as much again" cycles."

Comment: @ChristophPacher `T *p = new T(); delete p; p = new T(); delete p; ...`

Comment: @delnan thanks, just realized I read your comment the wrong way